How can the reals be the set of all points on a number line when there exist non-constructible reals?
We are given the intuition that the reals form all the numbers on the numberline. However, this intuition wasn't working for me as the existence of non-constructible reals seems to me to imply that some reals cannot lie on the numberline- as it seems if $r$ is a non-constructible real, the fact that $r$ is on the numberline means that there exists a point on the numberline measuring $r$ away from $0$, implying that it is possible to measure a line segment of length $r$ on a straightedge, meaning that $r$ is constructible. This contradicts that $r$ lay on the numberline.
I would be greatly appreciative if someone could reconcile my intuitions about what it means for a real  number to lie on the numberline, and for a real number to be constructible. How could a real number be on the numberline and yet be non-constructible?
EDIT:  Although it has been pointed out that the straightedge used to a construct number has no markings and can only connect 2 points, isn't it still the case that it is theoretically possible to measure out a non-constructible number using a straightedge, even if there may be no defined process to do so- the mere fact that there exists a line segment of length $r$, if $r$ is any real number, seems to imply that there exists a way to arrange 2 points $r$ apart and then connect them. Why is this theoretical possibility of tracing out something of length $r$ not sufficient to conclude that $r$ is constructible?

In straightedge and compass constructions, the straightedge has no markings, i.e. it is not a ruler. You cannot measure distances with it, only draw straight lines passing through two given points.

Suppose you had a tape measure that could measure to the eighth of an inch.  And you needed to measure $\frac 3{16}$.  You would not be able to do it with that tape measurer.  But that tape measure is not the only tool.  Nor are straightedge and compass the only tool. But even if you had no tools that doesn't mean the number can't exist. Take $\pi$ for example. We can't measure that with decimal tape measure of compass and straightedge. we can measure it with a wheel though. But even if we couldn't that doesn't mean it can't exist.

Even with other constructions (which can only have finite many steps) we can construct only countable many real numbers. In fact, most real numbers cannot even be described nor be computed , but the real line contains no "holes" , all the numbers are somewhere. A final remark : In reality , you cannot even exactly half a distance , the construction only works in theory with absolute exact construction steps.

Sounds like you are very much confused by the notions of real numbers, Euclidean geometry, etc., which results in a very unclear question. My suggestion is to pick up a modern book on foundations of Euclidean geometry (say, Greenberg's book) and start reading. While you are at that, start asking yourself questions such as "What is a `numberline'? Is it a meaningful concept?" "What are constructible numbers and how do they differ from real numbers?" ...

"Constructible" has a very specific meaning in this context, using the tools of straightedge and compass in specific ways. It is not just a "theoretical possibility of tracing out something of length $r$."

I think perhaps you have misunderstood the definition of a constructible number, which I'll repeat from that wikipedia link with some additional details.
One starts from the Euclidean plane, and a unit length segment on that line, and one names the endpoints of that segment $O$ and $A$. So, for example, one can use the ordinary Cartesian coordinate plane, and the $x$-axis, and the segment $[0,1] \times \{0\}$ on the $x$-axis, and one names $O=(0,0)$ and $A=(1,0)$. Given a real number $r$, to say that $r$ is constructible means that starting from the two points $O$ and $A$ we can produce a finite sequence of points one-by-one
$$P_0 = O, P_1 = A, P_2, P_3, ..., P_N
$$
where each step is one of a very restricted set of constructions, so that eventually our sequence contains two points $P_i$ and $P_j$ whose line segment $\overline{P_iP_j}$ has length equal to $|r|$.
The allowed constructions are motivated by the methods of Euclid's elements, and they are carefully laid out on this wikipedia page. Here is a description which is couched in modern "mathematical induction" language.
Assuming you have already constructed the points $P_0,P_1,P_2,...,P_n$, the next point $P_{n+1}$ is constructed by the following procedure: first choose four of the points $P_i,P_j,P_k,P_l$ with $0 \le i,j,k,l \le n$ that have already been constructed, and now carry out one of the following three constructions:

If the two lines $\overleftrightarrow{P_iP_j}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{P_kP_l}$ are not parallel, then $P_{n+1}$ may be their point of intersection.
If the line $\overleftrightarrow{P_iP_j}$ intersects the circle having center $P_k$ and radius $\overline{P_kP_l}$, then $P_{n+1}$ may be one of the intersection points.
If the circle having center $P_i$ and radius $\overline{P_iP_j}$ intersects the circle having center $P_k$ and radius $\overline{P_kP_l}$, then $P_{n+1}$ may be one of the intersection points.

For any real number $r$ there are of course many, many, many line segments of that length in the Euclidean plane. BUT, it is possible that none of those line segments will have the format $\overline{P_i P_j}$ using only the construction methods listed above. One way to easily convince yourself of the truth of this statement is that the set of all possible points $P_i$ is countable, and therefore the set of all lengths of segments $\overline{P_i P_j}$ is countable, but the real numbers are uncountable.

The constructions listed above are sometimes called straightedge and compass constructions, likely because of their relation with the practices of ancient masons and architects and the tools that they used. But one should not be misled by that terminology: the exact mathematical constructions must still be carefully described.
In your final paragraph you alluded to the possibility of other ways of "tracing out" a number which is not constructible. For example, the neusis construction was used in antiquity to trisect an angle; and in modern language, by extending the three constructions above to also allow the neusis construction, one can "construct" a nonconstructible number (and now, as perhaps you can observe, the "c" word has been overused and we should be more careful with our language).
In summary, there are indeed more exotic kinds of constructions which produce more and more exotic kinds of numbers. This was (and perhaps still is) an active topic of research over the millennia. However, the modern mathematical term constructible number is unambiguous: you are only allowed to use the three constructions listed above.

Constructible numbers are exactly the length of lines which can be made with a compass and straight edge of unit distance.
Sure you can use a straight edge to draw a line which contains many real numbers; however the only number we have 'constructed' is the length of the line, not each point on the line.
